# If $2\arccos(\frac45)-\arcsin(\frac45)=\arctan(y)$ then find the value of $y$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If $2\arccos(\frac45)-\arcsin(\frac45)=\arctan(y)$ then find the value of $y$

**My Attempt:**

Using $2\arccos(x)=\arccos(2x^2-1)$, I get

$$2\arccos(\frac45)=\arccos(2\times\frac{16}{25}-1)=\arccos(\frac7{25})$$

Also,

$$\arcsin(\frac45)=\arccos(\frac35)$$

Now, using $\arccos(x)-\arccos(y)=\arccos(xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2})$, I get

$$\arccos(\frac7{25})-\arccos(\frac35)=\arccos(\frac{21}{125}+\frac{24}{25}\cdot\frac45)=\arccos(\frac{217}{125})$$

But $\arccos$ input can't be greater than $1$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that surprisingly (and contrary to popular belief, including yours unfortunately!)...

$$21 + 96 \neq 217$$

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: It’s always refreshing when someone incorporates humour into their post!

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer We need more young people on math.SE 

Answer (score 1):

Since $$7^2 + 24^2 = 25^2$$ and $$3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2,$$ it follows that
$$\frac{24}{25} = \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{7^2}{25^2}},$$ and $$\frac{4}{5} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{3^2}{5^2}}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{7}{25} \cdot \frac{3}{5} + \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{7^2}{25^2}} \sqrt{1 - \frac{3^2}{5^2}} = \frac{21}{125} + \frac{96}{125} = \frac{117}{125}.$$

In particular, $$21 + 24 \cdot 4 = 21 + 96 = 117.$$

Comment: Thankyou.......